# Spring MVC default controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration, routes

I have a temporary solution for this and I'll explain it bellow, but I'm looking if there's a better solution.

I have a basic Spring 4 MVC app with web.xml configurations (no maven). The web.xml is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app ...>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

and the dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans ...>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
    <bean class="controllers.Controller"></bean>
    <bean class="controllers.HomeController"></bean>
    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />
</beans>
```

I deleted the part where it would create a simple in-xml (`urlMapping`) controller for the index view, simply because the index page needs some backend work done as well.

Currently all `/` requests are handled by the `Controller` class, while all `/home/` requests are handled by the `HomeController` class (because spring, by default, makes a path so controller name is the primary url path, right?)

My question is, is it possible and if yes, how can I make the `HomeController` class my default controller. Just so I don't actually have to have a `Controller` class.

For those familiar with ASP.NET MVC, what I want is how whether you go to `site.com/Home/Index` or just `site.com`, both the times you reference the same controller.

I want to create it so spring automatically connects `site.com` to a route in `HomeController` class.

I hope I'm clear enough. I'll answer any unclear questions and welcome any answers or documentations! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not just using Spring Boot? If you did, you'd just have to put `@RequestMapping("/")` on the method and not think about anything else.

Comment: @chrylis I know, I started using Spring Boot, but then was informed that I had to get around without it (configurations are a must). It's not a personal project.

Comment: So you have an employer who's actively insisting on using outdated tools for a new project, and not even applying best practices in using a dependency manager? Good luck.

Comment: @chrylis it pays until the next job :) but I know what you mean...

Comment: If you're not gonna use spring boot, it's ok, but even with plain spring mvc, you can live without `web.xml` and stuff. Spring has a great doc, so..

Comment: @AliDehghani had no idea. I'll look it up, thanks!

Comment: Even without Spring Boot, you can still use `@RequestMapping({"/", "/home"})` on your controller (although I don't know whether the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping bean will interfere with this).

Comment: @whistling_marmot tried, it does interfere, sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't actually tried this, but I think it should work.

Create a new class that extends `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping`, and override the `generatePathMappings` method so that if the controller is annotated with `@RequestMapping` then it will use that annotation's value as the path instead of the controller's name.

```
public class MyControllerClassNameHandlerMapping extends ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping {

    @Override
    protected String[] generatePathMappings(Class<?> beanClass) {
        if (beanClass.isAnnotationPresent(RequestMapping.class)) {
            RequestMapping mapping = beanClass.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
            return mapping.value();
        }
        return super.generatePathMappings(beanClass);
    }
}
```

Annotate your `HomeController` at the class level (not the method level) with `@RequestMapping({"/", "/home"})`.

In the bean definitions of *dispatcher-servlet.xml*, replace Spring's `ControllerClassNameHandler` with `MyControllerClassNameHandler`.

Comment: You sir are a wizard! I honestly haven't thought of doing that, I just thought there was a built-in way to do this. But modifying that class did it as well.